# program doesnt work with fgets but works with gets function

Tags: stdin, fgets, getchar

i have used gets at first and tried to compile and run. It worked perfectly.
then i changed it to fgets as the compiler warning said me to do so.
I tried getchar() and fflush() after looking in some other posts but it doesnt work.
This is the part of the code:

```
 int main(void){
 char  line[1024];             /* the input line                 */
 char  *argv[64];              /* the command line argument      */

 while (1) {                   /* repeat until done ....         */
      printf("shell> ");         /*   display a prompt             */

      fgets(line,20,stdin);    /*   read in the command line     */

      parse(line, argv);       /*   parse the line               */
      if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0){    /* is it an "exit"?     */
           exit(0);
        }

  execute(argv);           /* otherwise, execute the command */
 }
```

}

Can anyone tell me what part have i been doing wrong?

Comment: fgets() leaves the final "\n" in the string intact. gets() does not.

Comment: If you want to process the command line arguments, why use `int main(void)`, not `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`? What command line arguments did you use, or perhaps, you are not really using command line arguments?